# PHP Getting all file names in dirctory for page switching

Tags: php

Right now I have all my pages under a switch case for when a visitor uses whatever.php?p=pagename

Here is how it is currently

```
switch($page)
    {
        case 'about':
            include('pages/about.php');
            break;
        case 'contact':
            include('pages/contact.php');
            break;
        case 'edb':
            include('pages/edb.php');
            break;
        case 'eluna':
            include('pages/eluna.php');
            break;
        case 'mercsys':
            include('pages/mercsys.php');
            break;
        case 'pastebin':
            include('pages/pastebin.php');
            break;
        case 'projects':
            include('pages/projects.php');
            break;
        case 'sites':
            include('pages/sites.php');
            break;
        case 'soon':
            include('pages/soon.php');
            break;
        case 'sqlgen':
            include('pages/sqlgen.php');
            break;
        case 'wcms':
            include('pages/wcms.php');
            break;
        case 'add':
            include('pages/add.php');
            break;
        case 'edit':
            include('pages/edit.php');
            break;
        case 'delete':
            include('pages/delete.php');
            break;
        case 'moveAnnouncement':
            include('pages/moveAnnouncement.php');
            break;
        default:
            include('pages/404.php');
    }
```

My question is, How can I shorten this down to a foreach loop and use the page names for each .php in the pages/ directory without having to add each individual one or any future pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**upd:** like @svrnm adviced, you can do some security checks if you not did it before:

```
$filename = realpath('pages/' . $page . '.php');
if($filename && file_exists($filename)) {
    include($filename);
}
```

or/and you can build files whitelist first:

```
$whitelisted = glob("*.php");
if(in_array($page . '.php', $whitelisted) && file_exists($filename)) {
    include($filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your top example is what I was really looking for. Saves me a lot of lines, cheers!

Comment: I wouldn't do this without some further security checks, e.g. someone could set $page to `../unaccessible_file.php`! I would recommend some kind of whitelisting (`if(file_exists($filename) && in_array($filename, $files)) ...`) or at least using `realpath` to check if the file path still is within `pages/ ...